# Как реализовать задержку timeout в Express.js при оброботке запроса?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, settimeout

У меня есть функция оброботки пост запроса внутри которой я тестирую валидность 2 mail аккаунтов с помощью библиотеки [emailjs-imap-client](https://github.com/emailjs/emailjs-imap-client) , подключаясь поочередно к первому и второму. Если оба подключения прошли успешно посылаю `res.send(true)` если в одном из двух произошла ошибка подключения, тогда в блоке catch цепочки промиссов посылаю `res.send(false)`.

```html
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    const port = data.ssl ? 993 : 143;
    const client = getImapClient(data.host1, port, data.username1, data.password1);
    const client2 = getImapClient(data.host2, 993, data.username2, data.password2);

    client.connect()
      .then(() => {
        client.close();
      })
      .then(() => client2.connect()
        .then(() => {
          client2.close();
        }))
      .then(() => res.send(true))
      .catch((e) => {
        res.send(false);
        console.log(e);
      });
});
```

Но есть одна загвостка: Ошибка вылетает если пробовать подключится к существующему imap серверу но с неправильными данными аккаунта и тут всё ок. Но вот например может существовать почтовый сервер mail.lol.ru который слушает на порту 143 и если к нему подключится но на порт 993 (порт ssl) то начнется просто очень длинное время ожидания.И в итоге мой сервер не может выслать ответ клиенту так как тупо ожидает ответ от почтового сервера . В итоге ошибка подключения конечно появляется но спустя минуты.

Нужно чтобы мой сервер внутри этой миддлвары/функции ждал ответа от почтового сервера не больше 5 секунд а потом если
тот еще не ответил отправить клиенту `res.send(false)` и до свидания.
Подскажите как это правильно реализовать . Думаю можно с помощью функции `setTimeout` но не знаю как.

PS: Как бонус если знакомы с промиссами и библиотекой emailjs-imap-client можете дать советы как лучше реализовать проверку а то какая то мутная цепочка получилась. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, откуда функция getImapClient - в исходниках библиотеки emailjs-imap-client её нет. Я понимаю, что это Ваша функция, код которой Вы не привели здесь.

Внутри Вашей функции есть вызов

```
var client = new ImapClient(host[, port][, options])
```

Иногда полезно просмотреть исходники - там сразу видно, что после инициализации клиента мы можем выполнить ещё одну команду:

```
client.timeoutConnection = 5 * 1000 //Milliseconds to wait for the IMAP greeting from the server
```

Всего есть 3 вида таймаутов, которые Вы можете переопределить, посмотрите часть исходного кода библиотеки:

```
const TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = exports.TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = 90 * 1000; // Milliseconds to wait for the IMAP greeting from the server
const TIMEOUT_NOOP = exports.TIMEOUT_NOOP = 60 * 1000; // Milliseconds between NOOP commands while idling
const TIMEOUT_IDLE = exports.TIMEOUT_IDLE = 60 * 1000; // Milliseconds until IDLE command is cancelled

class Client {
  constructor(host, port, options = {}) {
    this.timeoutConnection = TIMEOUT_CONNECTION;
    this.timeoutNoop = TIMEOUT_NOOP;
    this.timeoutIdle = TIMEOUT_IDLE;
```

Comment: Странно что в документации они это не уточнили . Вы мой спаситель)

Answer (score 2):

Ответ с настройками лучше, но если отвечать именно на заданный вопрос, то можно подписаться на такой промис:

```
Promise.race(yourPromise, new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(rej, 1000, "timeout")))
```

Comment: Всё равно спасибо . )